# MySQL does not decrement when it's 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have

```
UPDATE topic SET liked = liked - 1 WHERE id='$id'
```

It does not decrement when the `liked` is `0`.

What I have to do in order to decrement the field `liked` when `liked` is `0`?

Note: It works when it is not 0.

Edit: `liked` is int.

Comment: can `liked` be negative? What is its data type?

Comment: Make sure `liked` is not unsigned.

Comment: Which datatype is "liked" defined as?

Comment: What's the datatype of the liked-table?

Comment: Your `liked` column is probably an unsigned int.

Comment: @juergend, it is int. It can be negative.

Comment: @george: I'd double check that...

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-contained example? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @gbn, http://i.imgur.com/DZVXd.png

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to have a floor of zero?

```
UPDATE topic SET liked = liked - 1 WHERE id='$id' AND liked > 0;
```

If you want negative numbers you need a [SIGNED datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html) of course. However, you need to be aware of limits to avoid errors. See ["Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)

So assuming liked is changed to `SIGNED TINYINT`...

```
UPDATE topic SET liked = liked - 1 WHERE id='$id' AND liked > -128;
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to set the `liked` column to SIGNED.

eg.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl` CHANGE `liked` `liked` INT(10) SIGNED
```

Comment: As far as I can see from Navicat it was already signed. Anyway, I've run the code successfully but it did not have any effect. It works only if the integer is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `UNSIGNED` integer it can't go below 0 but if I got u right - you can decrease value when it's below 0? If so, have you tried quoting the values? Maybe that's the problem that MySQL equals 0 to NULL? Try like this:

```
`liked` = (`liked` - 1)
```

Comment: it makes it -1 if it is not 0. for example if i have 5 it becomes -1. when there is no apostrophe  it has no effect on any number.

Comment: Ok I've checked everything myself, it works perfectly when it's SIGNED INT, this is test code: UPDATE `test` SET liked = liked - 1 WHERE 1 and if you put second liked in quotes like this: `liked` - then you get wrong result